# Mostrar imagen almacenada en servidor en php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando hacer una galería de fotos a modo de aprender un poco a programar en php, pero me he estancado a la hora de querer mostrar las imágenes.

Las imágenes están almacenadas en el servidor y la ruta en la base de datos. El problema es que todo el div que muestra la imagen, con titulo y descripción, está en php y no consigo que se vea también la imagen.

Adjunto:

```html
<?php

$consulta = "SELECT nombre, archivo, descripcion FROM imagenes ORDER BY RAND()";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or trigger_error("error de consulta");

if($resultado){

while ($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

 echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
 echo  '<img src="'.$col['archivo'].'" alt="" class="img-rounded">';
 echo  '<div class="caption">';
 echo   '<h4>';
 echo    $col['nombre'];
 echo   '</h4>';
 echo   '<small>';
 echo    $col['descripcion'];
 echo   '</small>';
 echo  '</div>';
 echo '</div>';

}
$resultado->close();
}
$conexion->close();

?>
```

El nombre y la descripción si que se muestra, pero he intentado de mil maneras que se muestre la imagen y nada.

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que imprime `$col['archivo']`?

Comment: la ruta de la imagen

Comment: ¿Y esa ruta es accesible? Es decir, es una ruta que apunta directamente a un .jpg (por ejemplo) y no require autenticación. ¿Esa ruta es de un servidor de internet o de un fichero local de tu equipo?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el html resultante?

Comment: De casualidad, si tu ruta esta bien. Tendrá permisos tu carpeta para lectura y escritura?

Comment: Me he fijado que en el html si que muestra la ruta de la imagen, pero luego en la página no se ve.

Comment: La ruta es de un fichero local

Comment: Si no me equivoco, desde Chrome no se puede acceder por seguridad a ficheros locales, debes habilitarlo. Prueba esta solución http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/windows.html y si no funciona, prueba este plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb

Comment: ¿La ruta es relativa al docroot de la web? Si es así, ¿cuándo la armas completa que error observas?
Ejemplo `src="fotos/foto1.jpg"` y tu url base es `http://localhost/mi_web/` entonces la url completa es `http://localhost/mi_web/fotos/foto1.jpg`.

Answer (score 3):

Me atrevo a decir que el problema tiene que ver con la ruta de tu imagen como te ha comentado El Asiduo en tu pregunta.

Pongamos un ejemplo. Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente ruta guardada en nuestra base de datos:

```
C:/AppServ/www/ibroms/admin/properties/uploads/imgprinciple/02-07-2016-1467494058-luxorhome.jpg
```

Y nosotros podemos visualizarla correctamente a través de nuestro explorador de archivos de Windows:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, cuando nosotros introducimos la ruta en nuestra etiqueta `<img>`, la imagen no aparece tal y como lo deseamos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y nos muestra en la consola el siguiente error: **Not allowed to load local resource**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este error se debe por que uno nunca podrá ser capaz de mostrar imagenes directamente en el navegador dando la ubicación de la carpeta donde se almacena, para eso es conveniente usar un servidor (ya que tu lo estas haciendo desde un servidor local).

Supongamos que mi servidor se llame de la siguiente manera (lo que viene por default al instalar AppServ -similar a Xammpp- `http://localhost/`

Entonces nuestra opción sería renombrar nuestras rutas con el siguiente código y utilizando la función [substr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php), la cual nos devuelve una parte de la cadena.

```
 $cadena = substr($reg['rutaImagenPrincipal'],15);
 $localhost = 'http://localhost/'.$cadena;
```

¿Qué hace esta función? Bueno, retomando nuestra ruta `C:/AppServ/www/ibroms/admin/properties/uploads/imgprinciple/02-07-2016-1467494058-luxorhome.jpg`, analiza la cadena y a partir del caracter 15 la 'parte', regresandonos la siguiente cadena: `ibroms/admin/properties/uploads/imgprinciple/02-07-2016-1467494058-luxorhome.jpg` y después la concatenamos con la ruta que nos abrirá, teniendo como resultado esto: `http://localhost/ibroms/admin/properties/uploads/imgprinciple/02-07-2016-1467494058-luxorhome.jpg`

Y pudiendo, ahora si, visualizar correctamente nuestras imagenes en nuestro servidor local.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tienes alguna pregunta o no comprendes, no dudes en decirme, con gusto te ayduaré. Éxito y buenas vibras!

Comment: Excelente guía para ir más allá del "no se ve" sino poder diagnosticar ¿por qué?

Comment: Aclararía que `C:/AppServ/www/` es el docroot. Es decir, que es de alguna manera el directorio que se accede cuando se coloca la URL base (`http://localhost/`) en el navegador.